# Why does playground prepend getter results with "some"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, swift-playground

I translated the Objective C code of Stanford's Card Game tutorial into Swift and was playing around in Playground to check it out.

However when I call the property getters of my PlayingCard instance, Playground prepends the result with "some":

```
class PlayingCard:Card{


    var suit:String? = "?"
    var rank:Int?

    func getSuit() -> String{
        return self.suit!
    }

    func setSuit(suit:String){

        let validity_check = self.validSuits.contains(suit)
        if validity_check{
            self.suit = suit
        }

    }


    func setRank(rank:Int){
        if rank <= maxRank{
            self.rank = rank
        }
    }



}



var array:Array = ["hi", "world"]

array.contains("HI")


let cardtest = PlayingCard()
cardtest.suit => returns {some "spade"}
cardtest.getSuit() => returns "spade"
cardtest.rank => returns {some 10}
```

What does this mean? why does it return that in the property getter but not in a custom getter function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your property is defined as `String?` its value is actually an OptionalString enum that indicates whether it has a value (some) and its value.

The reason that getSuit just returns "spade" is that it is defined as `-> String`.  If you change it to `-> String?` then you will get the same result - `(some "spade")`

If you change your line to `cardtest.suit!` then you will get the value "spade" - the ! unwraps the optional value